# Nuget component missing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package, toolbox

I am trying to implement web browser according to this article from msdn.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Professional-WebBrowser-dac9c5d0#content
But I have trouble with point 4.2 Adding The NuGet features. I successfully installed the DockPanel Suite via Manage NuGet Packages. This application is WinForms in Visual Studio 2012. After this instalation I should see the DockPanel component in toolbox, but I cannot find it. I tryed everything but still nothing.

Comment: That's entirely normal.  You write *code* to use DockPanel Suite, it is not a point-and-click component.  Progress to step 4.5, "A little coding".

Comment: Really? After reading the article above I realized it is point-and-click component.

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is:

1. Open Solution Explorer.
2. Open the References folder of your project.
3. Find the reference named 'WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking'.
4. Right-click the reference, and then click Properties.
5. In the Properties window, find the **Path** item.
6. Double-click the value of the **Path** property in order to do a 'Select All,' on it, and then do a Copy to the clipboard.
7. Right-click the **Toolbox**, and then choose **Choose Items** from the menu.
8. Click **Browse** on the **.NET Components** tab.
9. Paste the path in the Browse dialog box's **File name** field, and then click **Open**.
10. A new checked item, **DockPanel**, should be visible in the list.  Ensure that the check box next to it is checked, and then click OK.

After following these directions, then a **DockPanel** item should be visible, and you can just drag it to the Designer.

Please note, these directions are for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium.